# Unable to locate package: Import Error Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a code base which has the following structure.

```
--project
     |
     core
     |  |-- __init__.py
     |  |-- core_function.py
     |
     executor
        |-- __main__.py
        |-- executor_1.py
```

The content of the files are as follows:

- core/**init**.py

```
def run_engine():
    print(running engine)
```

- executor/**main**.py

```
from core import run_engine
# Some Other Functions.....
```

The package `core` gets recognized if the module is executed the following way

```
/project>python -m executor
# No error
```

But in case, when the module is called directly, it throws error

```
/project>python executor
# Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
```

Also if find_packages() is execurted in the `__main__.py` file, it would list `core` as a package.

**How can the `core` package be used without using sys.path.append ?**

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you adding the function in the `__init__.py` ?

Comment: In the actual package, __init__ contains the import from submodules. Above is just for representation